# Update step in Fenwick Trees

Tags: algorithm, fenwick-tree, binary-indexed-tree

My question concerns the full reasoning behind the update step in Binary Indexed Trees (Fenwick Trees). As such, when updating our array with a certain increment, at a certain position, the update goes like this:

```
void updateBIT(int BITree[], int n, int index, int val)
{
    // index in BITree[] is 1 more than the index in arr[]
    index = index + 1;

    // Traverse all ancestors and add 'val'
    while (index <= n)
    {
       // Add 'val' to current node of BI Tree
       BITree[index] += val;

       // Update index to that of parent in update View
       index += index & (-index);
    }
```

My problem is with the `index += index & (-index);` part. Please note that I understand the `index & (-index)` bit, especially in the context of querying the tree.

I've tried several examples by hand using this index update rule, but I haven't been able to find the logic behind adding `index & (-index)` in order to go to the next node that needs to be updated.

From what I got up until this point, a node `i` in a BIT is 'responsible' for the original values in the array ranging from `[i - i & (-i) + 1, i]`, so that implies that any node would fall into a range of this form. Specifically, as I understand it, when wanting to update position `k` in the original array, we follow the following steps (conceptually, not in the actual code):

- Iteration `0`: update `BIT[k + 1]` (indices are shifted by `1` in the
  BIT array) . While still at iteration `0`, we update the index we're
  looking at, so I'd assume that we're looking for the next smallest
  interval that's responsible for node `k`,  hence we need to find the
  next index `i` where `i - i & (-i) < k < i`. Find this index `i` by
  incrementing the current index by `k & (-k)`.

The rest of the iterations occur in the same fashion until we go off limits. I've tried numerous examples by hand, and I still don't get why adding `i & (-i)` takes us to the right next node. Each and EVERY tutorial I found on the web, including videos, is completely dodgy on this matter.

There are several related questions about BITs here, **please don't merge them with mine before reading it carefully**. To my knowledge, this particular question has not been answered.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me try to explain the above scenario by taking a simple example.

Let's take `i = 12`. Now we Update `BIT[12]`. Now next step according to the algorithm to update is `i += i&(-i)`.

What is 12 in binary = `01100`. The last bit set is `2`, the value is `2^2` = 4 (as you know

```
0th bit value is 2^0 = 1
1st bit value is 2^1 = 2
2nd bit value is 2^2 = 4.
```

In similar fashion for other bits.

So now next index that we will update is `12 + 4 = 16`. i.e `BIT[16]`.

Now this was about how the system works. Let me try to explain in simple words why this technique works.

Let's Say I need to update `index = 1` and let's say MAX array value is 8. So what all index I will update `1,2,4,8`.

Now, let's say I need to update `index = 3`. So the array indexes will I update `3,4,8`.

So you see how till now `BIT[4]` has got sum of all the values from array index `1 to 4`.

Now suppose you need to get total sum for first 4 numbers, you just do `BIT[4]` and you will traverse through indexes `4,0`. In short you don't traverse through `1,2,3`. As we have seen how those indexes were covered because of bit manipulation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, this is exactly the algorithm I posted.. My question was WHY does this work, within the context that I outlined, why do we select indices following this rule...

Comment: My bad, got it, let me update my answer with some base examples and show why it works always.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned before, I'm well aware of the fact that the rule works as I've done countless examples by hand, such as the ones stated by yourself. As it stands, I know that, say for the index `1`, indices `2`, `4`, `8` should be altered and that's exactly what the update rule provides as a result. My question was, **WHY** is it always the case that the `index += index & (-index)` rule takes us through the right path? What's the meaning of this operation, in your words?

Comment: So, the way I got feel of this part is through observation which even you have tested out on paper or the example which I have provided, we see that every number can be represented in binary as power of two and adding the last set bit of a number gives us next right path. Hope this helps in someway.